# How to make saved images to retain saved in Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

After some time all images in my Whatsapp look in the following way

[image]

i.e. as if I never downloaded them. Although I did.

How to make it keep images once downloaded?

Comment: You download an image from WhatsApp, the same image ***still exists*** in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/`, and WhatsApp shows like it's not downloaded? Android version and ROM?

Comment: What's your os? android version? Sometimes (in rare cases tho) there is autodelete function enabled in some roms by default. AND do you use any 3rd party app to free up storage?

Comment: Did you possibly move them to an sd card or something to save space?

Answer (score 0):

Open a file manager app and go to folder
WhatsApp > Media > WhatsApp Images
and check if your images are still in that folder. If not, you can try downloading them from WhatsApp again, refresh the folder, and see if they appear there.